# Auto Layout for complex view in Table View Cell

Tags: ios, autolayout

I know this might not be the best question but I really need to a starting point:

If I wanted to create a layout as the one below (using auto layout):

[image]

What I tried was:

- Put the Three zeros in a horizontal stack view
- Then put the three labels (posts, followers, following) in a horizontal stack view.
- Then put those two horizontal stack views above into a vertical stack view.
- Then I added that gray button below the (posts, followers, following) labels into the vertical stack view created right above. So in the end I had one vertical stack view consisting of two horizontal stack views and the gray button.
- Finally I added the image to the left in the vertical stack view created in the above step which made a final horizontal stack view. This step ruined my layout completely. Made the image like 500 width which made the stack view go off the screen. So I set layout constraints on the very last horizontal stack containing the image, gray button, and two horizontal stack view to `Bottom Space: 140, Top space 10, Leading Space 20, Trailing space 20`. (I didn't touch the stack views inside this final stack view. I only put layouts on the main horizontal stack view created in this step).

**After 4bar suggestions:**

[image]

Please note I have not touched the first name, facebook.com, or bio label at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not set the distribution mode for your outermost horizontal stack view, it will default to UIStackViewDistributionFill, in which case the arranged subviews will stretch to fill the whole width according to their hugging priority. Increase the content hugging priority on the image view (say, to 251) to prevent it from stretching. Also, if the image size is larger than the space you'd like to devote to it, you may also need to set additional width or height constraints on the image to override its intrinsic size.

The main thing to understand is that UIStackView's size is driven by the intrinsic sizes of its arranged subviews, plus spacing. In Fill mode, if too much space is available, content hugging priorities are used to determine which view to stretch; if too little space is available, compression resistance priorities are used to determine which view to compress.

Comment: Ok so I changed the distribution mode to fill equally. Now it looks much better. I have updated how it looks in my post above. Now to go on with the image. Can I just limit the width and height of the image view and make the mode aspect fit. It seems to work like that as well as shown in my post above.

Comment: Also for some reason even though the posts label is showing up as `p...` in the Main Storyboard, for some reason it showing up as `posts` when I run the actual app. Do you know the reason for that? Is that because the compression resistance is calculated when I run the app and it checks that against the compression resistance priority I set during the constraints in Main Storyboard?

Comment: To give the right-hand vertical stack the maximum amount of space, you probably want Fill rather than FillEqually; then adjust the relative content hugging priorities so that the right-hand view stretches while the left-hand one doesn't. You can then, yes, also set width, height, and/or aspect ratio constraints on the image view.

Comment: Not sure why your preview in the storyboard is not matching what you see on your device. Are you setting the preview size to match?

Comment: I am a little bit confused on the content hugging priorities. Like right now the `(post, follower, and following)` label are all 251 for their vertical and horizontal content hugging. So in my case I want all three of these labels to be the same size somehow. How would I use content hugging for that case? Right now I just changed the text to `Minimum Font Scale` set to 0.5 which caused the text size of each label to be different sizes as shown above in the second picture.

Comment: I expanded my answer to try to clarify. The right-hand horizontal stack (post, follower, following) would be the perfect use case for fillEqually or perhaps equalSpacing, whichever you think looks better. Study the docs for [UIViewStackDistribution](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistackviewdistribution) for the details.

Comment: That explanation helped a lot. But in my case wouldn't I have to specify compression resistance priorities. Since in my case (for example on an iPhone 5 screen) too little space is available so it puts the `...` in the following and follower labels. If I decrease the compression priorities for following and follower labels then those will shrink correct? Last question: I am just confused on whether I should set those priorities on the labels itself or the stackview?

Comment: It depends on the distribution mode you have selected; again, follow the link to the docs above to see the details on what role hugging/compression priorities play in each mode. These priorities are set on the arranged subviews, i.e. the labels. Another example, getting back to your original question, you would set hugging priority on the right-hand vertical stack view, relative to the left-hand image view, because they are arranged subviews of the outermost horizontal stack. (You could think of them as siblings.)

Answer (score 0):

As shown below, You need to set the width of the stackView containing the image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image to look like a square, you have to pin the width and height of the image to the same value. Then set Mode to AspectFit so that image won't look stretched.
Pin the width of the labels like 'posts'. So that they will show the entire text.